# How to call python api method inside another api in same class?

Tags: python, api, flask

I have the following api method

```
@app.route('/api/v1/lessons', methods=['GET'])
def api_lessons():
    if 'courseId' in request.args:
        courseId = request.args['courseId']
    else:
        return "Error: No course id provided. Please specify an course id."

    onto = get_ontology("ontology.owl")
    onto.load()

    result = onto[courseId].contains
    result2 = []

    for i in result:
        temp = "{ id : " + str(i.Identifier) + ", name : " +  str(i.Name) + "}"
        print(temp)
        result2.append(temp)

    return json.dumps(result2)
```

And I need to add a new method to call this api internally with same args

```
@app.route('/api/v1/learningPath', methods=['GET'])
def api_learningPath():

    lessons = api_lessons

    return json.dumps(result2)
```

How to do that ?

Comment: Don't call the API, call the method: `lessons = api_lessons()`

Comment: And after calling the method, refer to the captured return value in `lessons`, don't refer to `result2`, that's a local variable of `api_lessons()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function instead of calling an internal API. Your `api_lessons()` will return a JSON string and you will need to parse it back to JSON in order to use it. Your function would be like this.

```
@app.route('/api/v1/learningPath', methods=['GET'])
def api_learningPath():

    lessons = json.loads(api_lessons())

    return json.dumps(result2)
```